# c# server and mobile client implementation handshaking timeout error

Tags: c#, android, ios, sockets, websocket

I want to create a server-client application where a server is in c# code and a client application is in Android & iOS.

A server implementation is done using [asynchronous-server-socket-example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/asynchronous-server-socket-example)

We are testing our server(C#) implementation using below android application
[sockettest](https://apkpure.com/socket-test/net.thundertechapps.sockettest)
and [SocketTest](https://github.com/akshath/SocketTest) windows application. Our server working perfectly on these both applications.

I used followings for android client implementation

[java-android-websocket-client](https://github.com/gusavila92/java-android-websocket-client)

[websockets-on-android](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/learn-to-use-websockets-on-android-with-okhttp-ba5f00aea988)

[socket.io-client-java](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-java)

and iOS implementation using

[socket.io-client-swift](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift)

[socket.IO-objc](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc)

We are able to connect wss://echo.websocket.org:443(Online test server) on both platforms(Android & iOS), but not our server. We are getting same logs in a console on client applications(Android & iOS). Showing console logs like

"handshaking..." than after few seconds shows "connection timeout.", "disconnected."

Please refer below links for logs on Test Server.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1um7QWtsc9CJAN8myJPUvLMfOF-7_DRdO

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Nm-YEb_aWaPREKPa1bVMBI7J7GmzjDI_

Comment: obviously server is not accesible from devices with given connection (fx you are using server on local network and devices are not in the same network)

Comment: @Selvin thanks for replay ,when I test with local ip I will conform that my device also connect in same network.

Comment: ... or device has no acces to this machine ... or its firewall ... or certificate

Comment: @Selvin but as I define in question same device working with socket test application, that's test app only available In android.